# C++ Need help converting string to tchar, tried some things from other posts, but not working

Tags: visual-c++

This is my first C++ program I have written, so I am by no means a c++ programmer, so please be kind. I needed to be able to connect to a database, get a link and then download the file from that link. Everything works except I have to hardcode the link rather than use the link I have saved in a string. 
I just need to convert my string into a tchar and have tried a few things, but it's not working. I need the TCHAR url[] to have the value in the string dotnetlink, instead of the hard coded url that is currently in there. Thank you for your help.

```
string dotnetlink;
//REQUEST URL FOR DOWNLOAD
send(Socket,"POST /getdotnetlink.php / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.domain.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n", strlen("POST /getdotnetlink.php / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.domain.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"),0);
    char buffer[10000];
    int nDataLength;
    while ((nDataLength = recv(Socket,buffer,10000,0)) > 0){        
        int i = 0;
        while (buffer[i] >= 32 || buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\r') {
            //LINK TO DOWNLOAD STORED IN THIS STRING
            dotnetlink = dotnetlink + (buffer[i]);
            i += 1;
        }
    }
closesocket(Socket);
WSACleanup();
cout << dotnetlink;
const TCHAR url[] = _T("http://www.linktomydownload.com/file.exe");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCHAR is just a typedef for either CHAR or WCHAR, depending on whether the UNICODE macro is defined. This means that if UNICODE is not defined no conversion is needed. If it is defined, you can use the [MultiByteToWideChar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx) function to perform the conversion.

As a tip, TCHAR and the related "T"-prefixed macros and typedefs are things from the Windows 95 days, when Unicode support wasn't very broad. Nowadays you should always use Unicode, except for places that actually require byte strings (such as the HTTP protocol).

Here is an example of how you might do it:

```
WCHAR szDotnetlink[256];
int length = ::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, dotnetlink.c_str(), -1, szDotnetlink, 256);
if (length == 0)
    // the conversion failed
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not quite sure if I follow. The MultiByteToWideChar function seems like overkill, but maybe i'm just not used to c++. What it comes down to is I need to replace the hard coded text in TCHAR url[] with the value in string dotnetlink. Is this really the easiest way? If so, I will try and figure it out. Also, any code suggested would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's actually the easiest way to do it. I've updated the answer with an example.